# How to store the index of a list item in to a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ms-access, asp-classic

I have a unordered list in which I would like to search through and find the index of each item. After, I want to save that index value to a column in my access database.

So far the javascript I have is below, all this does currently is loop through the items. How can I assign that index value to a variable in ASP? or maybe a textbox.

```
function sort() {
  var count = document.getElementById('sortable').getElementsByTagName('li').length;

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      alert(i);
    }
 }
```

The ASP for the list is below,

```
<ul id='sortable'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use asp.net `HiddenFields` & set its value?

Comment: as suggested by Krishna, use Hidden fields (the basic HTML ones as you don't use .NET). Note also that the `index()` method of jQuery can be of use here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier if you count the items in the backend instead. If you do it on the client side (with JS) you will have to send the data back to the server.

If you want to use the index on the client side (or pass it to the server at some point) you can do something like this:

```
function sort() {
  var items = document.getElementById('sortable').getElementsByTagName('li')
  var count = items.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      items[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
    }
 }
```

This will result in:

```
<li data-index="0"></li>
<li data-index="1"></li>
<li data-index="2"></li>
...
<li data-index="n"></li>
```

Comment: Although this is helpful, It's still not finished yet. Can I update an Sql string within the JavaScript?